# Nav pull-left and pull-right elements wont sit aligned to each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've seen this problem before but cant get it to work on my simple footer. It has a list on the left and another on the right but they wont sit level with each other and the list on the right doesn't sit lined up under the header

[image]

As you can see the left side looks fine but the right is doing all sorts of wrong things

Here is the html

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="navbar-text pull-left">
        <nav> 
    <h4>Boring Links</h4>

    <ul class="pull-left">
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Terms", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Privacy Policy", root_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
      </p>

      <div class="navbar-social-accs pull-right">
       <nav>
        <h4>Follow Us!</h4>
    <ul >
      <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Terms", root_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to "Privacy Policy", root_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
    </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</footer>
```

How do I get the right side to sit level with the left and have the `ul` sit under the heading text like the left side is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/mPXOrv)**

It looks like you were just wrapping a `<p class="navbar-text pull-left">` element around the first `nav` but not the second one. So I just removed that and it fixed the spacing issues. For bootstrap footers i feel like most of the time it is easier to use standard `col`'s just for future reference.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-social-accs pull-left">
        <nav>
          <h4>Boring Links</h4>

          <ul class="pull-left">
            <li>
              <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Terms", root_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Privacy Policy", root_path %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-social-accs pull-right">
        <nav>
          <h4>Follow Us!</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "About", about_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Terms", root_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Privacy Policy", root_path %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks but the `ul` don't sit right compared to the `h4` they are a fair bit to the right. I'm not the best with bootstrap so maybe `col` is a better option. If its easier what do I need to replace to just use `col`?

Comment: `.navbar ul{ padding:0 }` removes the default bootstrap padding on `ul` elements